# Let L be a splitting field of polynomial P in K[x]. Is it true that the number k extension automorphisms of L is [L:K]

Tags: galois-theory, splitting-field

Let L be a splitting field of a polynomial P in K[x]. Is it true that the number of k extension automorphisms of L is [L:K]? (A k extension automorphism is a ring automorphism which preserves scalar multiplication by k.)

Comment: This is true if and only if the polynomial is separable.

Comment: Thank you very much!